# How to expose ports?

Tags: docker, openflow

I am trying to expose two ports in docker container 6633 and 8080 , and try to connect one application from external host,in simple term I am trying to connect Open-Flow switches running on external host to Open-Flow controller running on docker container,But I am not able to connect,how am I suppose to expose the ports in docker and get this connection done?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to do this once on your host, and assuming they are TCP ports, you can 'publish' them like this:

```
sudo docker run -p 6633:6633 -p 8080:8080 my_image
```

The -p option is described more at the top of this page: http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

Comment: Note that this will expose them on a random high port on the host running Docker. You'll have to check `docker ps` to see which.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply,but even if I expose these port I am not able to connect mininet switches to Open-Flow controller running in container, Am I doing any wrong step?

Comment: Suggest you supply more information about what you tried and what the symptoms were.  Maybe use something like 'tcpdump' to see if the packets show up where you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using dockerfile? In the dockerfile, you could simply add this:

```
EXPOSE 6633
```